# Grouped bar plot using replicates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't find the answer looking in other group bar plot conversations. Each rename (or site name) should add up to 100% but the bars add up to more than that. I am wondering if I have my data set up incorrectly.

I also want to add error bars, but maybe once I get the replicates correct I can figure that out.

```
testData <- read.csv("composition.csv")
testData$id <- as.factor(testData$rename) 
testDataMelt <- reshape2::melt(testData, rename.vars = "rename")
ggplot(testDataMelt, 
       aes(x = rename, y =value, group = replicate, fill = replicate)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  xlab("Lake") + 
  ylab("% of Sediment Mass") +
  labs(fill = "") + 
  scale_fill_grey()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to summarise your data before (calculate mean and se per rename).

Comment: please show your data using `dput(my_data)` rather posting a picture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @PoGibas, here is an example with summarizing your data before passing it to `ggplot`.

Because I do not have your data in a easy to use format, I'll make some fake data for 3 sites; gravel, sand, silt & clay sum up to 100% for each row as in your original data.

```
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.frame(rename = c("HOG", "MAR", "MO BH"),
                 gravel = sample(20:40, 9),
                 sand   = sample(40:50, 9),
                 silt   = sample(0:10, 9))
df$clay = as.integer(100 - rowSums(df[,2:4]))
```

Here is a solution with `data.table` (this package needs far more advertising) for computing the means and standard errors (to be used for error bars).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table) # for aggregations 

# Convert to data.table object and 
# calculate the means and standard errors of each variable per site.
setDT(df)
testDataMelt <- melt(df, id.vars = "rename")
testDataMelt_agg <- testDataMelt[, .(mean = mean(value), 
                                     se = sd(value)/.N), 
                                 by = .(rename, variable)]
# The mean percent of sediments sum up to 100% for each site.
# We are ready to make the graph.

ggplot(testDataMelt_agg, 
       aes(x = rename, y = mean, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  # Add error bars (here +/- 1.96 SE)
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = mean + 1.96*se, 
                    ymin = mean - 1.96*se),
                position = "dodge") +
  xlab("Lake") + 
  ylab("% of Sediment Mass") +
  labs(fill = "") + 
  scale_fill_grey()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!  I was not familiar with data.table. So great to know-I appreciate it.